# get specifc node position using xpath

Tags: xpath

I've been strugguling to select a specifc node.
My query consists of two operations. First I need to get the position of a node using this:

```
count((//th[text()="TEST"])[1]/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

and then I do this

```
(//th[position() = count((//th[text()="TEST"])[1]/preceding-sibling::*)+1])
```

When I test this query on chrome, it doesn't work. but when I execute them separately it works. Any idea what is wrong ?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>TEST</th>
        <th>TVA réduite<sup>(2)</sup></th>
        <th>Prix TVA 20%</th>
        <th>Surface</th>
        <th>Etage</th>
        <th>Orientation</th>
        <th>Cave</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-lot-id="0098__981104102">
        <td>My Value</td>
        <td>462 000€</td>
        <td><strong>525 500 €</strong></td>
        <td>100.23m²</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Est</td>
        <td>Non</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: It may help if you can post the relevant part of the html you are working with.

Comment: @JackFleeting done, my bad

Comment: No problem :) Now - what exactly is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to get the value based on the header.

**Scenario 1:** Get td value based on th (header)

```
 //td[position()=count(//th[normalize-space(.)='TEST']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

*Screenshot:*

[image]

**Scenario 2:** Select the header based on the header text position(you don't need such a complex xpath for this simple though ;-) )

```
//th[position()=count(//th[normalize-space(.)='TEST']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

*Screenshot:*

[image]